# apply SVN Patch in sub folder

Tags: svn, path, patch

My hard disck is: `steps/scenarios/foo.feature` and `steps/foo.patch`

```
Index: scenarios/foo.feature
===================================================================
--- scenarios/foo.feature
+++ scenarios/foo.feature
@@ -24,6 +24,10 @@
     And abcd
     Then abcd

+    ##patch for IC
+    Then efgh
+    ##end patch for IC
+   
     Then abcd
     And abcd
```

I want change path of my patch in `steps/ic.foo.patch` so I modify my patch file to:

```
Index: ../scenarios/foo.feature
===================================================================
--- ../scenarios/foo.feature
+++ ../scenarios/foo.feature
@@ -24,6 +24,10 @@
     And abcd
     Then abcd

+    ##patch for IC
+    Then efgh
+    ##end patch for IC
+   
     Then abcd
     And abcd
```

But I have this error: failed hunks: 1